# Let $t(x)$ and $w(x)$ be two continuous functions such that $\lim_{x \to \infty} t(x)=\lim_{x \to \infty} w(x)=0$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $t(x)$ and $w(x)$ be two continuous functions such that
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} t(x)=\lim_{x \to \infty} w(x)=0.$$
Then either prove or disprove by a counter-example the following questions:

(i) Suppose $\displaystyle\int_7^{\infty} t(x)\, dx$ diverges and $t(x)\leq w(x) \leq 0$ on the interval $[7,\infty)$, then $\displaystyle\int_7^{\infty} w(x)\,dx$ must diverge.

(ii)  Suppose $\displaystyle\int_7^{\infty} t(x)\,dx$ diverges and $w(x) \leq t(x) \leq 0$ on the interval $[7,\infty),$ then $\displaystyle\int_7^{\infty} w(x)\,dx$ must diverge.

**Answer:**

(i)

This is **false**.

We have to show a counter-example to disprove it.

Let $t(x)=-e^x$ and $w(x)=-\dfrac{1}{x}.$ Then $t(x) \leq w(x) \leq 0$ on $[7,\infty).$

Also,
$\displaystyle\int_7^{\infty} t(x)\, dx$ diverges while $\displaystyle\int_7^{\infty} w(x)\, dx$ converges.

(ii)

This is **true.**

$\displaystyle w(x) \leq t(x) \leq 0$ on $\displaystyle[7,\infty) \implies\int_7^{\infty} w(x)\,dx \leq \int_7^{\infty} t(x)\,dx \leq 0.$

Since $\displaystyle\int_7^{\infty} t(x)\,dx \leq 0$ diverges, $\displaystyle \int_7^{\infty} w(x)\,dx$ diverges.

**I need confirmation of my work.**

Comment: $-\int_7^\infty \frac{1}{x}dx$ does not converge. Also $\lim_{x\to \infty} -e^x = -\infty \neq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumptions are correct.

You are quite close to perfect demonstration but you should use $w(x) = -\frac{1}{x^2}$ and $t(x) = -\frac{1}{x}$.

Answer (score 1):

An easier example for case 1 is w(x)=0.